# Why is the output of this program 312213444 and not 3122134?

Tags: c, data-structures

In the code given, the output that I can think of is 3122134 because the the last printf statement gets executed only once when n=1. so condition become 1>1 which is definitely not true and the loop exits and the last printf statement is executed. but the original output is 312213444. Why is it so ? Where am I going wrong ? kindly explain every concept and instance of it ?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 void count (int n)
 {
 static int d=1;

 printf("%d", n);
 printf("%d", d);
 d++ ;
 if(n>1)
 count(n-1);
 printf("%d", d);
 }

 void main ()
 {
 count(3);
 }
```

Comment: The last printf gets executed once in every recursive call, not just in the base case. There's no else after the if.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite your `printf()` statements (and fix your `main` declaration), for example into

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void count(int n)
{
    static int d=1;

    printf("A) n = %d\n", n);
    printf("B) d = %d\n", d);
    d++;
    if (n>1)
        count(n-1);
    printf("C) d = %d\n", d);
}

int main(void)
{
    count(3);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile and run the code, and look at the output, and you shall understand.

---

One technique that can help unravel recursive functions, is to unwrap a couple of the recursive calls into separate functions. Here, `main()` calls `count(3)`, which does a recursive call `count(2)`, which does a recursive call `count(1)`. We can change these recursive calls to calls to separate functions by repeating the function three times. We do need to change the `d` variable into a global, though, so that each of the function copies uses the same one, instead of separate copies that just happen to have the same name.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int d = 1;

void count1(void)
{
    int n = 1;
    printf("count1(): A) n = %d\n", n);
    printf("count1(): B) d = %d\n", d);
    d++;
    /* The following is never true, so
       we comment it out:
      if (n>1)
          count0();
    */
    printf("count1(): C) d = %d\n", d);
}

void count2(void)
{
    int n = 2;
    printf("count2(): A) n = %d\n", n);
    printf("count2(): B) d = %d\n", d);
    d++;
    if (n>1)
        count1();
    printf("count2(): C) d = %d\n", d);
}

void count3(void)
{
    int n = 3;
    printf("count3(): A) n = %d\n", n);
    printf("count3(): B) d = %d\n", d);
    d++;
    if (n>1)
        count2();
    printf("count3(): C) d = %d\n", d);
}

int main(void)
{
    count3();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In this particular case, unraveling the recursive function should help understand control flow. (Specifically, that when you call another function, and the function returns, the execution continues in the caller in the statement following the function call.)

Comment: why does this printf("C) d = %d\n", d); statement executes 3 times, when it should have only been executed one time and come out of the loop and terminate ?

Comment: @akashdubey: Why do you think it should have been executed only once? When you call a function, and the function returns, the execution continues at the statement following the function call. It seems like you think it should somehow return back to main.

Comment: Because,When  n =1, the if (n>1) condition fails and the control goes to printf("C) d = %d\n", d); and it should come out the loop once it is executed, but it does not seem to do so. It executes the last printf statement two more times and this is what is confusing me.

Comment: @akashdubey: There is no "loop"; this is recursion. When a function call returns, the execution continues in the caller normally, in the statement following the recursive call. In this case, after the innermost call `count(n==1)` prints the first `C) d=4`, the execution returns to the earlier recursive call, `count(n==2)`, which prints the second `C) d=4`, and then the execution returns to the first `count(n==3)` call, which prints the final `C) d=4`, before returning to `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are recursively calling the function

> count()

you are putting each call of count() on the stack of your application. After the last call of count is finished you return to the last call of count, which also prints the static variable d (which is only initialized once) again and so on, until the stack is finally on top and it goes back to the main method. This is why you are getting the last two '4' in your output.

Comment: can you explain it again using some diagram or anything for what happens to the stack when the program executes ?